# Can you animate borders with jQuery? Is there a plugin available?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I need to animate a border in jQuery. More specifically, the colour of the border.

I'd prefer to not resort to a 1px high div background colour animating or the like.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh looks like this one can do it!

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color